# Defining Matrix in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, matrix, syntax, syntax-error, sage

I'm quite new on Jupiter Notebook and I don't really know phyton, could someone tell me how to define a matrix? I mean, what should I write after:

```
A = [···]
```

I've tried "A=Matrix(QQbar, 2, 2, [1,2],[3,4])" and some similiar options but it always report "too many arguments in matrix constructor".

Thanks

Comment: Describe your environment and a package which you are trying to use, please. It's not `numpy.matrix`, and jupyter-notebook with python seems not to have any `show` method by default, which you mention in the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After a while I was able to find it out by myself, I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do it but since it works it helped me:

```
A = Matrix(2, 2, [1,2,3,4])
```

This code will define A and when you write A and press Ctrl+enter you will get something like this:

[1 2]
[3 4]

It may not seem to be a Matrix but if you write the following then it will print a real matrix:

```
show(A)
```

Hope I can help someone!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `numpy` array:

```py
import numpy as np

m1=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])  # this will result a 2x3 matrix
m2=np.array([3,6,9])  # and this will result in a 1x3 matrix
```

Also, as a bonus you can make a vector matrix multiplication with `m1.dot(m2)` and this result is a 2x1 matrix. Multiplication result will take the row count of `m1` and column count of `m2`.

Answer (score 0):

The Matrix function has a function definition after you type `Matrix()` which shows the arguments required to run which are `row, col, [listed matrix]`

We use

```
init_printing()
```

after importing Sympy in my math course.

Using that, you can just simply type the variable or multiple using

```
(a,b,c,d)
```

as a code line.